# Project Server SSRS report - One report dynamically including multiple reports

Tags: ssrs-2008, report, business-intelligence, subreport, ms-project-server-2010

I am not an expert at SSRS but have played around with it to know my basic way around it but I am stuck on this one. This is for Project Server 2010. I am working on a task to create two reports, and combine them at the end. First report, reportA is for a single project, pulling all of it's information. reportB is for a "Portfolio" of the projects on the server.

I am being asked to create a report of them merged. I guess we will call this reportC. reportC will have reportB at the very top, listing all of the projects and other basic information. If reportB has 10 projects listed, 10 reportAs (having information for every single project listed) and all their information, will be aggregated to the bottom of the report.

I tried looking into subreports but do not think this is what I am looking for because it doesn't look as if subreports can be added dynamically, unless I'm wrong. Any ideas on how to easily complete this? I appreciate any help I can get.

EDIT: Here is an example. No it wont be aligned like that. They gave me their example in Excel. It does not necessarily mean that reportC has to be through Excel. Could this be possible running a script of some kind or similar? 
[Basic Example](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TPI3z.png)

Comment: Can you give some visual representation of what you are trying to achieve? Do reports A & B have the same columns? Is report B a repeated header row with report A acting as the child details? I'm having trouble picturing what you want

Comment: I added a screenshot. I hope that helps?

Comment: If I were you I would go back to the sub-report route.
You are looking at it a little wrong in that they won't need to be created dynamically, you will create just 1 version of each report and then create a click through link passing a parameter which would contain a project ID/code and then use that to populate the child report.
They would not be visible as per your example though

Comment: The issue with that is that they want all of the reportAs readily available. The main concern is that if they want to  print, they can easily just print out a file and have them all already there. I don't think a click through link would give them what they are looking for. I was looking into adding tabs for each project report but I am concerned about navigating and the mess of a file it may become.

Comment: I have explored dyanmic graph creation myself recently and I couldn't find a reliable way of doing it. If you get an answer to this please let me know, I would be interested to find out

Answer (score 0):

I recently did something very similar myself.

What you could do, is in report A, place a table at the bottom where each row is a sub-report (report B). This would allow for all the passed data (name, report id, etc.) to generate visible sub-reports beneath the origin report.
Then, if you want each sub-report on its own page, you can go under group properties and add a page-break after each group.